# React Native doesn't re-render when re-opening app

Tags: react-native

I have a functional component in my react native app that has an event listener watching the app state in order to clear out a cache when the app is closed.  This works as expected, and I have logic written in a `useEffect` block to add/remove this event listener when the app is closed.

The functionality works perfectly when the user either navigates elsewhere in the app or closes the app, but when the app is re-opened after closing (not fully shutting down the app, just moving to a different app) the page is not re-rendered and so the event listener is not re-added.

I've attached the code in my `useEffect` below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!listenerRef.current) {
    toggleEventListener(true);
  }
  return () => {
    toggleEventListener(false);
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use appState from react-native to see foreground and background events

https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work by the design pattern suggested in the article you linked.  The eventListener should be removed when exiting the app or navigating elsewhere (as shown by the `subscription.remove();` line within the `useEffect` return statement), so it won't be possible to detect when the app is re-opened.

Comment: @WillG have you tried it, i think it will work.

Comment: Yes I tried it and no it does not work, per the reason I said in my first comment

Comment: Following up here, any other ideas?

Comment: to be honest I am not entirely sure what your issue i have the exact same logic in my app and appState works.

I have an appState hook that listens to foreground and then i reapply the subscription

Comment: are you actually removing the eventListener when you exit the app, like it shows on the page  you linked?

Comment: your question doesnt ask about removing the event listener it asks about adding it.  If the user minimizes i don't remove the event listener but sometimes it gets removed anyway, my code readds it when the app is reopened.

Comment: Okay, so do you see how if an event listener has to be added when the app reopens…it can’t detect the app reopening.  That’s the problem